# Remove \x in string in python

Tags: python

I need get little endian random string via python.
Such as '0010' as 256 (without '\x')
 
Here is my code.

```
 import random
 import struct
 str1 = struct.pack('<Q', random.randint(1, 1000))
 #Ex: str1 = '\xc9\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

But I don't have any idea to convert this string to "C902000000000000"
Please give any advise, thanks

Comment: Do you want the hexadecimal representation of that string? `struct.pack` gives you the bytes.

Comment: as a note, `\x` is *not* a string, it's an escape symbol that shows that `\xNN` is one single unprintable character!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another alternative, which is quite easy to type, is the following approach:

```
>>> import random
>>> import struct
>>> str1 = struct.pack('<Q', random.randint(1, 1000))
>>> str1.encode('hex')
```

Answer (score 2):

as an alternative to @msvalkon's solution, you can use the `binascii` package, which does the same, but more elegantly:

```
>>> import random
>>> import struct
>>> str1 = struct.pack('<Q', random.randint(1, 1000))
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(str1)
'c902000000000000'
>>> binascii.hexlify(str1).upper()
'C902000000000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct.pack()` returns you the bytes as specified by the format character. If you want the *hexadecimal* representation of the bytes, you'll need to convert them. You can use string formatting for that:

```
>>> import random
>>> import struct
>>> str1 = struct.pack('<Q', random.randint(1, 1000))
>>> "".join("{:02X}".format(ord(x)) for x in str1)
'C902000000000000'
```

Remember that in python, the hexadecimals are just strings, which prevents any meaningful manipulation. You can convert them to integers with `ord()`:

```
>>> list(map(ord, str1)) # Or a list comprehension, [ord(x) for x in str1] 
[201, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the "\x" from "\x0034" simply using this code
if the ax variable contains the string

```
ax = ax.replace("\x00" , "")
```

then the \x00 will removed from the string

Comment: this would remove the x00 as well in addition to the 34